# Best way to format string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++17

In `javascript` I can format a string using `template string`

```
const cnt = 12;
console.log(`Total count: ${cnt}`);
```

if I work with `python` I can use the `f-string`:

```
age = 4 * 10
f'My age is {age}'
```

But, if I working with `C++(17)` what is the best solution to do this (if it is possible)?

Comment: Install [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), then you can do `fmt::print("Total count: {}", cnt);`.

Comment: `std::cout << "Total count: " << cnt << std::endl;` Works with stringstream too

Comment: I don't know what's the problem well. but if u want to use numbers with the strings here is an example. `size_t age = 40; std::string str = "My age is  "+ std::to_string(age);`

Answer (score 13):

I think the simpler way is `std::to_string`:

```
std::string str = "My age is ";
str += std::to_string(age);
```

`std::ostringstream` also works nicely and can be useful as well:

With this at the top of your source file

```
#include <sstream>
```

Then in code, you can do this:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "My age is " << age;
std::string str = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf(dest_string, "My age is %d", age).
```

but using sprintf will rase an error, so best use snprintf:

```
snprintf(dest_string, size , "My age is %d", age);
```

where `size` is the is the maximum number of bytes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow David.  Unfortunately, answers in "C" for questions tagged as C++, while valid, tend to get downvoted.  (Disclaimer: I didn't downvote, but have been a victim of this culture as well)

Comment: While this solution *can* work in C++, it is based on C and is not a good solution for C++, as it lacks adequate type checking and buffer overflow checking, things that C++ has solved with other solutions.

Comment: Which other solution? Interesting that *A Tour of C++ (Third edition)* of Stroustrup (so a very short and essential guide of C++ to C++23) explains also such C method (but none of the rest of c library). Until std::format is in wide use (still not available on many compilers now), there is no perfect C++ solution. I think we should trust Stroustrup.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `std::format()` is great but not perfect, the perfect one is `std::print()` which prints to `std::cout` by default to save you some typing. Basically making it a modern `fprintf()`.  Unfortunately, one has to wait for C++23. Another problem is that `std::format()` and `std::print()` heavily use template meta-programming and also lacks optimizations. Currently, a single print can take 5 - 10 second to compile. Worse, if the arguments are incorrect, the present error messages are completely unreadable, making development a pain. Until those problems are solved...

Comment: @比尔盖子: but it is also the reason it is so useful. No hardcoded formatting (split presentation from model): it allows to rephrase without worry to change code (and to translate, e.g. feeding it to gettext). Output routines are very slow, call kernel, etc., so we should not overoptimize. IMHO both ways sucks, and there is not yet a wonderful solution (which we all will love), by allowing good i18n and split presentation, and to do proper type checks.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I was referring to compiler performance, not binary performance. On my server, I found a simple C++ source file with `printf()` and `std::cout << string` took 1.5 seconds, but `std::print()` and `std::format()` took 10 seconds (!) on GCC 14. This severely decreases productivity... clang is slightly better and took half the time. Hopefully, this problem will be eventually fixed, either by compiler writer or by Moore's law... Otherwise, I agree with you, micro-optimizing `print()` is usually an pointless endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to stdout:

```
const int cnt = 12;
std::cout << "Total count: " << cnt << "\n";
```

Writing to any other stream works similar. For example replace `std::cout` by a `std::ofstream` to write to a file. If you need the formatted string:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Total count: " << cnt << "\n";
std::string s = oss.str();
std::cout << s;
```